# On the norm of a linear operator

Tags: real-analysis, linear-transformations

We have, for $A\in L(\mathbb{R^n}, \mathbb{R^m})$, $||A||$ = $sup_{|x|\leq 1} |Ax|$.

Thus, an example we were given in lecture was the following:

> $A: \mathbb{R^2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R^2}$. $$Ae_1 = 10e_1$$ $$Ae_2 = \dfrac{1}{2} e_2$$
>
> $||A|| = sup|Ax| = sup \sqrt {(10x_1)^2 + (x_2/2)^2)} \leq sup \sqrt {(10^2x_1^2 + 10^2x_2^2)} = sup 10|x| = 10$.

Does  this simply mean that the norm of the operator $A$ is bounded by 10? Is there no way to find a smaller bound?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume by $e_1,e_2$ you mean the standard basis vectors in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Choose the particular $x=e_1$, then $|x|=1$ and 
$$ \|A\|\ge\frac{|Ax|}{|x|} = |10e_1| = 10.$$
Combined with your upper bound, we get $\|A\|=10$.

Comment: Sorry if I'm being dense, but how did you go from $\dfrac{|Ax|}{|x|}$ to $|10e_1|$?

Comment: No worries. Since I choose $x=e_1$, I have $|Ae_1| = |10e_1|$ and $|x|=|e_1|=1$.

Comment: Ah I see! So when you choose $x = e_1$ are you really saying $x = e_1 + 0e_2$? I'm just wondering why $e_2$ is disregarded here.

Comment: That's precisely what I did there (: In general, once you establish an upper bound for the norm of the operator (say $\|A\|\le C$ for some constant $C$, you then try to find an element $x$ in the domain of $A$ such that you obtain the lower inequality $\|A\|\ge C$.

Comment: Makes perfect sense, thank you!!!